# iOS Device Check - Server Side C# .net solution (JWT)

Tags: c#, ios, .net, swift, jwt

Setting up DeviceCheck on iOS is super easy, but implementing the server-side using C# is difficult as there are hardly any examples and some tricky JWT code is needed, which has to be absolutely perfect for it to work. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete solution. I stripped out the first and last line from the p8 file e.g. "key begins here" (or whatever) and also took out all the new lines so that the key was just one long line

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string deviceToken = ""; //you get this from the device
    string transcationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        { "device_token", deviceToken },
        { "timestamp", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds() * 1000 },
        { "transaction_id", transcationId }
    };

  
    var token = GetProviderToken();
    var payloadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.development.devicecheck.apple.com/v1/query_two_bits"))
        {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

            request.Content = new StringContent(payloadJson);
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;                    
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
    }
}

private static CngKey GetPrivateKey()
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(@".\applekey.p8.txt"))
    {
        var ecPrivateKeyParameters = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
        var x = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineXCoord.GetEncoded();
        var y = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineYCoord.GetEncoded();
        var d = ecPrivateKeyParameters.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        return EccKey.New(x, y, d);
    }
}

private static string GetProviderToken()
{
    var epochNow = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"iss", "<10 DIGIT TEAM CODE FROM APPLE DEV CENTER>"},
        {"iat", epochNow}
    };
    var extraHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"kid", "<THE NAME OF THE P8 FILE, 10 DIGITS>"}
    };
    var privateKey = GetPrivateKey();
    return JWT.Encode(payload, privateKey, JwsAlgorithm.ES256, extraHeaders);
}
```